# Is there a way to put a section of a line at the start of every subsequent line using regular expressions?

Tags: regex, notepad++, newline, capture-group, find-replace

I have a text file in which there is a line with the category and then all items of that category in lines below it. This is followed by 2 empty lines and then the title of the next category and more items in the category. I want to know how I could use regular expressions (specifically with Notepad++) in order to put the category at the start of each of the item's lines so I can save the file as a CSV or TAB file.

I started by isolating one of the categories as such:

```
Городищенский поссовет  1541
Арабовщина  535
Болтичи 11
Бриксичи    59
Великое Село    160
Гарановичи  34
Грибовщина  3
Душковцы    5
Зеленая 182
Кисели  97
Колдычево   145
Конюшовщина 16
Микуличи    31
Мостытычи   18
Насейки 5
Новоселки   45
Омневичи    53
Поручин 43
Пруды   24
Станкевичи  42
Ясенец  33
```

I then got as far as getting to be finding for

```
(.+)(поссовет)(\t\d{4}\r\n)(^.*$\r\n)
```

and replacing with

```
$1$2\t$4
```

which makes the first line

```
Арабовщина  535
```

turn into

```
Городищенский поссовет  Арабовщина  535
```

which is what I want to happen to the rest of the lines but I couldn't get any farther.

Comment: Needs more details. I suggest [edit]ing the question to show an input with three categories each with three or four lines (thus no more than about 20 lines in total). Then also show the expected output. However, I do not know of any way in Notepad++ of capturing a string and then inserting it into an unknown number of outlut lines. It is possible to do with multiple uses of "Replace all", but again we need to see the input and expected output. Really this task is better done with a custom written program.

Comment: I guess you would need to capture inside a lookbehind of variable length to achieve this which is not available in Notepad++. Would be something like [`^(?<=(.*\S)\s+\d+\r?\n[\s\S]*)`](https://regex101.com/r/5jGbR5/1)

Comment: To simplify you may want to do this in two steps: (1) *Find What:* `\r\n`, *Replace With:* `;` (2) *Find What:* `;;;`, *Replace With:* `\r\n`. Use another delimiter for your needs.